# Snoop does not recognize my program

Tags: wpf, snoop

I'm building a WPF 4 application.  In the past, Snoop was able to see the application, but now it does not.  This is true with Snoop 2.7.1 and 2.8.0.

That is, I click on the refresh button and my app does not show up in the drop-down control.  I drag the cross hairs over my window and it does nothing.

I really need to snoop my application as I'm debugging some template issues.  Can anybody help?

Comment: 2.7.1 works fine for me, try reinstalling?

Comment: Yep.. I also have 2.7.1 and it works OK with WPF applications (Net framework 4.0)

Comment: @TejasSharma:  I've uninstalled & reinstalled multiple times.  No difference in behavior.

Comment: Does your application require admin privileges? I read somewhere that if that is the case you need to run an elevated instance of snoop.

Comment: @TejasSharma:  That was it.  I had to run Snooop as Administrator and now it sees my program.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad to have helped. I'll post it as an answer for others who run into this problem.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Does your application require admin privileges? If that is the case you need to run an elevated instance of snoop i.e. run it as administrator.